# How to know the space of the internal storage used by my app in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, storage

How to know the space of the internal storage used by my app? Not also the cache but just the files of my app-specific internal storage.

And how to know the space used by the cache files of my app?

In other words, how to get these values programmatically? :

[image]